# Can't figure out how to make button be selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make it so that you can select the buttons on my quiz but I can't figure out how. I have it set so the option to go to the next page is hidden until you select something, however, I've spent most of today trying to find a way to actually select one of the buttons. I have the hover and active events assigned in my css, but don't know what to do to actually make the button when pressed stay selected.

We aren't allowed to use external libraries like JQuery. Is angularJS considered an external library? May have to ask the professor that.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:900|Roboto:400,100);
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px;
}

#myQuiz {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 650px;
  650px;
  position: relative overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}

#myQuiz h1 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size 2em;
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 36px;
}

myQuiz h1 span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans- serif;
  font-size: 3.2 em;
  line-height: 65px;
}

#myQuiz h2 {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#myQuiz h3 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#myQuiz p {
  margin: 0px 0px 14px 0px;
}

#myQuiz .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #7E3517;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#myQuiz .btn:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#myQuiz .btn:active {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#myQuiz .progress {
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 40px;
}

#myQuiz .progress div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

#myQuiz .progress div.on,
#myQuiz .progress div.answered {
  background-color: #ef0101;
}

#myQuiz .intro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 225px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 550px;
}

#myQuiz .intro p {
  margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
}

#myQuiz .question {
  width: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 225px;
  left: 50px;
}

#myQuiz .question .text {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  margin: 0px, 0px, 20px, 0px;
}

#myQuiz .question .ans {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 225px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding 10px;
  margin: 0px 15px 15px 0px;
}

#myQuiz .question .ans.selected {
  border-color: blue;
}

#myQuiz .question.unanswered .ans {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myQuiz .question.unanswered .ans:hover {
  background-color: rgba(163, 111, 155, .2);
}

#myQuiz .question.answered .ans {
  cursor: default;
}

#myQuiz .done {
  color: yellow;
  margin-top: 50px;
  transition: opacity 1.5s, margin-top 1.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

#myQuiz .done .btn {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

myQuiz .answered . done {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#myQuiz .results {
  position: absolute;
  top: 225px;
  left: 660px;
  width: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myQuiz">
  <h1>Spirit Animal Quiz</h1>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="on"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <form action="">
      <p> <input type="radio" class="btn" value="male"> Rough<br></p>
      <p><input type="radio" class="btn" value="female"> Soft<br></p>
      <p> <input type="radio" class="btn" value="other"> both </p>
    </form>
    <p class="text">How would you describe your skin?</p>
    <p class="btn">Rough</p>
    <p class="btn">Smooth</p>
    <p class="btn">Both</p>
    <div class=d one>
      <div class="btn">Next</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is angularJS considered an external library? **YES**

Comment: Thought so, was looking into right after I posted this. Only heard of it prior.

Comment: Not really important but why don't you use `<button>` instead of `<p>` for your, well, buttons? An `<ul>` would also make sense, I'd say.

Comment: You might want to try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36183750/361762

Comment: Awesome, something similar will hopefully help out. Thanks, I'll compare mine and that one after dinner.

Comment: I was originally setting it up to take the Questions and* answers from a JSON file, but because I'm supposed to have one question per page I didn't think it would work

Comment: Would SO be considered an "external resource"?

Comment: He has links to here and W3 schools and plus he said no exetrnal libraries nothing about resources.

Comment: I want it to accept any, guess I forgot to say it's a personality quiz. I need to  add values to each of the options and then by the end of the quiz give a personality, or in my case spirit animal, based on their choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css property `display` to show and hide your next button. 
use: `display: none;` to hide an element `display: inline;` to return to default
I gave the button and ID of "nxt" for easy access, and added event listeners to all of the buttons (because I don't know which one you want pressed before revealing next) With the onClick event you can do anything that should happen after the click in the callback function.

```js
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for( var i =0; i < btns.length; i++){
    btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
         document.getElementById("nxt").style.display = "inline";
    });
}
```

```css
#nxt{
    display: none;
}
#nxt, p.btn{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width : 150px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Find Out Your Spirit Animal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quiz.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id= "myQuiz">
        <h1>Spirit Animal Quiz</h1>
        <div class = "progress">
        <div class="on"></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>   
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        </div>

        <div class = "question">
            <form action="">
               <p> <input type="radio" class= "btn" value="male"> Rough<br></p>
                <p><input type="radio" class="btn" value="female"> Soft<br></p>
                <p> <input type="radio" class="btn" value="other"> both </p>
            </form>
            <p class = "text">How would you describe your skin?</p>
            <p class = "btn">Rough</p>
            <p class = "btn">Smooth</p>
            <p class = "btn">Both</p>
        <div class = done>
        <div class="btn" id="nxt">Next</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```